# OkHttp response cuts of after carriage return symbol

Tags: java, android, response, httpresponse, okhttp

I'm currently working on an android app that uses OkHttp for all the network communication with our server. Sometimes when we get a database error it dumps the error log in some XML and css combined output, for debugging purposes. But when using OkHttp to get the outputted text response from the server it cuts off  the actual response when it meets a carriage return.

I'm using this to get my response:

```
Response resp = client.newCall(request).execute();
String response = resp.body().string();
```

So when I try to print the `response` string it doesn't show the whole response. Is there a way to get okhttp to return the whole outputted text?

Answer (score 0):

It's unlikely that OkHttp is using the carriage return to delimit the end of the body. Try adding the logging interceptor & see what your webserver is returning for the response body encoding and content length. My guess is that the problem is on the server side here.

Comment: the thing is when I tried to use a desktop application, Postman, to do the same request, then I got the whole response and it was this way I noticed the differences between the two body contents

Comment: If this is a bug in OkHttp, please create an executable test case that reproduces the problem. If it isn't a bug in OkHttp, the process of building an executable test case should show you where the real problem is.